# Walking through this array, the key value is an illegal offset?

Tags: php, arrays, associative-array

So I have an array such as this:

```
$style  = array(
 'css' => array(
    'name' => array('core-css', 'babababa'),
    'path' => array(get_bloginfo('stylesheet_url'), get_template_directory_uri() . '/bababa.css')
    ),
 'js' => array(
    'name' => array('core-css', 'babababa'),
    'path' => array(get_bloginfo('stylesheet_url'), get_template_directory_uri() . '/bababa.css')
    )   
);
```

I can walk through in this fashion:

```
function load_css(){
    foreach($style as $key => $value){
        var_dump($key);
    }
}
```

Now the var_dump will return:

```
string(3) "css" string(2) "js" string(3) "css" string(2) "js"
```

The issue is that if I do var_dump($key['css]) or 'js' I get an illegal offset error.....

I need to check for both so I assumed doing:

```
if(isset($key['css']) && $key['css']){}
```

and then

```
if(isset($key['js']) && $key['js']){}
```

But alas it doesn't work.....

Can some one please tell me what I am doing wrong? I have walked through arrays like this countless times.... >.<

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php Good thing to read on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is proper PHP behaviour

```
$a = array(
    'key' => 'value';
);

foreach ($a as  $key => $value) {
     echo $key . PHP_EOL;
     echo $value . PHP_EOL;
}
```

will output

```
key
value
```

To get to name and path use:

```
$value['name'];
$value['path'];
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `$style['css']` or `$style[$key]`. The key itself is a string, not an array.

Answer (score 0):

Try using $value['name'] etc instead. The keys of the style array are 'css' and 'js', the arrays are in $value.

(Also, I assume it's just a typo in your question but you haven't closed the quote in `$key['css]` :-)